# Page will not navigate

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

After successfully creating a user, the use navigate function is supposed to take the user to the join room page on the website. However, after pressing signup the page does not change. My code is located down below.

Firebase still accepts the user and I can still view them on my console.

```
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Signup = ({ socket }) => {
    const currentUser = useContext(AuthContext);
   const navigate = useNavigate();
   const [err, setErr] = useState(false);
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reload

  const displayName = e.target[0].value;
  const email = e.target[1].value;
  const password = e.target[2].value;
  const profilePic = e.target[3].files[0];

  try {
     const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
     );

     const storageRef = ref(storage, displayName);

     const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, profilePic);

     uploadTask.on(
        (error) => {
           setErr(true);
        },
        () => {
           getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(
              async (downloadURL) => {
                 await updateProfile(res.user, {
                    displayName,
                    photoURL: downloadURL,
                 });

                 await setDoc(doc(db, "users", res.user.uid), {
                    uid: res.user.uid,
                    displayName,
                    email,
                    photoURL: downloadURL,
                 });
                 socket.emit("newUser", {
                    currentUser,
                    socketID: socket.id,
                 });
                 navigate("/join_room");
              }
           );
        }
     );
  } catch (err) {
     setErr(true);
  }
};
```